# Use function from other classes inside of main class android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

hello i have problem to load function from another class into main class in android java

package com.sourcebring.wordbring;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load default xml
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ntfi Notifi_engine = new ntfi();


        Notifi_engine.Send_notifi("hi", "welcome", R.drawable.wb_logo);

    }


}
```

and this is my class

```
package com.inc.project;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Action;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class ntfi extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void Send_notifi(String Title, String Content, int Icon)
    {
        // Create notification handler
        NotificationCompat.Builder notifi_Builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(Icon)
                .setContentTitle(Title)
                .setContentText(Content);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ntfi.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

        stackBuilder.addParentStack(WordbringMainActivity.class);

        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);


        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        notifi_Builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(0, notifi_Builder.build());
    }
}
```

with this code i have no error on program but when i compile project and i want to run it, my android program stopped.

but when i dont use ntfi class and i use this function `Send_notifi` in

```
MainActivity
```

there is no problem and program work successfully. i want to have this function `Send_notifi` in Separate class like top codes... what is the problem?

this is my error while run android app

```
05-08 19:41:44.510 918-918/com.inc.project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.inc.project/com.inc.project.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:127)
at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:75)
at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:3004)
at com.inc.project.ntfi.Send_notifi(ntfi.java:27)
at com.inc.project.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please follow proper Java naming conventions. And check your LogCat output for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because `NotificationCompat.Builder(...)` requires a `Context` object and since you've created the `ntfi` instance by yourself (it wasn't created by the system) even though it extends `AppCompatActivity` it isn't a valid `Context`.

What you can do instead is this:

```
public class ntfi {

public void Send_notifi(Context context, String Title, String Content, int Icon) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder notifi_Builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(Icon)
            .setContentTitle(Title)
            .setContentText(Content);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(WordbringMainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notifi_Builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notifi_Builder.build());
  }
```

and to show a notification:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ntfi Notifi_engine = new ntfi();
        Notifi_engine.Send_notifi(this, "hi", "welcome", R.drawable.wb_logo);
    }
}
```

Also, as a side note, you should consider following the Java naming conventions, start class names with a uppercase letter and variable names with a lowercase letter. As it is now, your code is very hard to read.

Comment: i changed it but now i have error on this line (Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ntfi.class);) and can not resolve method (getSystemService) on getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Answer (score 0):

You really do not need to have `ntfi` extend `AppCompatActivity`. All you need is to define a number of `static` methods in your `ntfi` class and then call these from within your `Activity`. In this case, you should then pass Context to these helper methods. Here is how you can change your `ntfi` class:

```
public class ntfi {

public static void Send_notifi(Context context, String Title, String Content, int Icon)
    {
        // Create notification handler
        NotificationCompat.Builder notifi_Builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(Icon)
                .setContentTitle(Title)
                .setContentText(Content);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, ntfi.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);

        stackBuilder.addParentStack(WordbringMainActivity.class);

        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);


        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                        0,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        notifi_Builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        mNotificationManager.notify(0, notifi_Builder.build());
    }
}
```

Then you could invoke the `Send_notifi` function like this:
`ntfi.Send_notifi("hi", "welcome", R.drawable.wb_logo);`
Note that in this case you do not have to instantiate ntfi - so get rid of the line : `ntfi Notifi_engine = new ntfi();`.

I hope this helps, by the way, it's not a good idea to name your class something like ntfi (small letters) think about some more descriptive name for class.

Comment: OK, cool, I am glad this helped. You can vote the answer if you find it useful. Enjoy coding!